# Python Blocking all instance on one input Socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

I am a Python newbie , here's the problem which i am facing . I am trying to implement a p2p DHT .

Well the scenario is as follows :

There's only program and I Run the same program in 7 different Windows ( Terminals ) . All of the 7 instances I run have 7 different socket nos and seven servers are created now

All of the terminals ( Server ) are waiting for a keyboard input at this moment , And I chose in one of the terminals and Input in one terminal , But rest all terminals are still waiting for the keyboard interrupt ( input ) ( it's obvious ) .

Now The terminal which I have chosen knows the peer id ( Socket port no of other terminals/Server ) , So now I want to send a message to other peers ( terminals ) , the problem is They are still waiting for the keyboard interrupt !

How do I solve this ? Essentially I want the rest all terminals to stop waiting for the keyboard input if in one of the terminals keyboard input is entered ( Note : I have all the socket ports of the rest )

It's a UDP connection

Comment: Do you have the code for the server waiting for the keyboard input, and also how they open the sockets? That would help people in answering your question.

Comment: @justhalf kinda of a trouble

Comment: Because in your current state, it's difficult to actually pinpoint the problem you have. Like Dhaivat Pandya said, the solution is to let the server sends a message to other servers. If your question is *how* to do that, we need to see your code architecture to be able to answer that properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need all of these servers to talk to one another (I'm assuming you have a good reason for all of these to be separate programs). In order to do that, there needs to be a socket or inter-process communication between each process.

Check [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to help you implement this more robustly.

Note that P2P protocols aren't exactly easy to implement.

Comment: Dude I know Socket Programming and also I said I have port nos of all the servers ... So this dint answer the question , can you please check the question once again ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html?  You can send a message to the other server instances after setting a handler for the event.

You can use http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill to send signals in between processes.

Comment: "On 7 _different_ Windows ( Terminals )"

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize that os.kill only works when the processes are only in the same terminal :(.

Comment: @timcour any other method ?

Comment: You could start a subprocess to listent for the keyboard input, then configure the main thread to listen on a socket for an "interrupt" signal that would be sent from the instance which received the keyboard input to all other running instances.  But then you'd need to keep track of all sockets on which servers are running.

Comment: Another idea is to use Redis.  Each running server would be able to "subscribe" to messages on a specified channel with a configured callback being called when a message is published to the channel.  A server receiving keyboard input would be able to publish a message to that channel on keyboard input... Is one of these solutions close to what you're looking for?